# Can Manitoba employers include a ban on duscussing or disclosing wages in their code of conduct?

Tags: labor-law, payment, non-disclosure

A similar question has been asked about BC and ON, but I cannot find any information on this in Manitoba. I know that in Winnipeg, at least one Winners and Marshall's location has explicitly barred this type of discussion in their staff code of conduct. Is this legal, and if not, does including it in the CoC function as a workaround for the employer?

Comment: Can you add a link to the other question, please